# PHP website form to database doesn't work

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I've currently made an php form on my website that sends the information to my database, but when someone uses it it only posts two of the 4 input fields to the database, see the image i linked below.

It's an refund site by the way written in Norwegian so, please use Google Translate if needed :D

Here's my refund.php:

```
    <html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" media="all" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>NattLAN</title>
    <meta name="author" content="ukieweb" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="soon, css3, template, html5 template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Balk - Page Template" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon.png" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p align="center"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/0128a30614276768bf956ad868604b5d/tumblr_n6zhprHRGv1qgefibo1_400.gif"></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3 align="center" color="black"> Refunderingsskjema</h3>
<form action="send.php" method="post">
<p align="center">Navn på deltaker:<br></p>
  <p align="center"><input type="text" name="u_deltaker" required><br></p>

<p align="center">Navn på betaler:<br></p>
  <p align="center"><input type="text" name="u_payer" required><br></p>

<p align="center">Telefonnummer:<br></p>
  <p align="center"><input type="text" name="u_phone" required><br></p>

<p align="center">Kontonummer:<br></p>
  <p align="center"><input type="text" name="u_konto" required><br></p>
<p align="center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send"><br></p>
</form>
<p align="center"><a href="help.php">Hjelp! Hva betyr alt dette ovenfor? KLIKK HER!</a></p>
</body>
</html>
  <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- footer socials -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="footer_socials col-sm-12 text-center">

                    <div class="contact_icons">
                        <ul class="contact_socials clearfix">
                            <!-- social icons -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                     <img src="oldwebsite/assets/nb.png" width="162" height="53" class="navbar-logo-img" alt="">
<div class="copyright">Kontakt: kontakt@nattlan.net</div>
<div class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2017 NattLAN</div>
```

---

Here's my send.php:

```
<title>NattLAN - Refund</title>
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn        = Connect();
$deltaker    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['u_deltaker']);
$payer       = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['u_payer']);
$phone       = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['u_phone']);
$konto       = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['u_konto']);
$query       = "INSERT into tb_cform (u_deltaker,u_payer,u_phone,u_konto) VALUES('" . $deltaker . "','" . $payer . "','" . $phone . "','" . $konto . "')";
$success     = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Fail".$conn->error);

}

echo "Success";

$conn->close();

?>
```

---

Here's my connection.php:

```
<?php
function Connect()
{
 $dbhost = "PRIVATE";
 $dbuser = "PRIVATE";
 $dbpass = "PRIVATE";
 $dbname = "PRIVATE";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

 return $conn;
}

?>
```

---

### My database only put's the two last information from the form in the database, image showing the problem:

Image form DB showing that it inputs 0's in two of the fields:

### https://prntscr.com/had0ak

Can someone help me figure out why this happens?
Thanks :D

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Output the query and see what you are sending. Also quoting integers won't help any.

Comment: `Use Google Translate if needed`; you are asking us to make your problem clear? Thanks for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's inserting `0` because the column type is `int`? Check on that and change to `varchar`.

Comment: Please set this answer as the correct one. That's my cookie!... man, he deleted the question.